# Azure DevOps multi repo trigger with a path trigger on the self repo

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, yaml, devops

I have the following requirement for an Azure Devops pipeline

- Needs to trigger on changes in specific path on the self repo (this works!)
- Needs to trigger on changes in another repo on the master branch (this doesn't work)

So I've done this:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - path/path/path

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repo-name
    type: git
    name: ProjectName/repo-name
    ref: master
    trigger:
    - master
```

Unfortunately, triggering from the master branch in `repo-name` doesn't work.
Is it not supported to have this setup? I've read on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) that multi repo triggers work, but all their examples are triggers on branches only. I have one that needs to trigger on a path.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve it myself and it's a bit of a d'oh answer. As you can see in my example, I had whitespace after `trigger: - master`     . That was the issue :-(